# Fuzzy Search for filenames with synonyms and tags (auto generated)

Tags: command-line, filesystems, ext4, search, tagging

Filesystem: Ext4

I create separate files for each topic.
I have thousands of files segregated into 2 or 3 levels of hierarchical broad categories. I would like to search for these files efficiently.

> For example, if I have a file Finance.md (not limited to markdown, e.g. Finance.tsv, Finance.txt, Finance.html, Finance.pdf), I would like following sample of tags to represent this file:
>
> loan, money, bank, investment, credit card, tax, Steuer (German word for Tax), tAX, Tax1

So, if I search with a particular tag, it shows all filenames that are represented by the tag.

How can I do this? Moreover is there a software which could auto generate this tag for each file, and store it as a list that can be inspected and edited for future use?

Also, may be when a new file is being created it would point that similar files based on the tags already exist.

Would be nice to restrict this function within a particular parent directory and not the entire file system. If its not possible on ext4, I am open to virtual file system that could be enabled for a particular folder inside EXT4 filesystem. Also, I would prefer an opensource CLI tool, but GUI tools are also welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should search for software, not filesystem. Your requirements are more like for specialized app like https://obsidian.md/

Comment: @RomeoNinov Please see edit:

not limited to markdown, e.g. Finance.tsv, Finance.txt, Finance.html, Finance.pdf

Comment: You have no problem to insert such files in to this notes program. About tagging - you can find some plugins for this purpose.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I was hoping for an open source and hopefully a CLI tool. But thanks.

Comment: I understand you, your requirements are quite specific, so maybe the reason there is no (as far as I know) such opensource software now.

Comment: I'd suggest that what you're looking for is a Document Management System. This is not my area of expertise but a two minute search suggests tools such as [OpenDocMan](https://www.opendocman.com/features/)